# What is the history of the PDP-11 MARK instruction?

Tags: history, software-development, pdp-11, instruction-set, architecture

[The PDP-11 MARK instruction](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2005/pdp11/pdp11-40-000107.html) was intended to be used as part of the standard PDP-11 subroutine return convention. `MARK` facilitated the stack clean up procedures involved in subroutine exit.

To use it, the caller would put the `MARK` instruction *on the stack*:

```
MOV R5,-(SP)        ;place old R5 on stack
MOV P1,-(SP)        ;place N parameters
MOV P2,-(SP)        ;on the stack to be
                    ;used there by the
                    ;subroutine
MOV PN,-(SP)
MOV #MARKN,-(SP)    ;places the instruction
                    ;MARK N on the stack
MOV SP,R5           ;set up address at MARK N instruction
JSR PC,SUB          ;jump to subroutine
```

At this point the stack is as follows:

```
OLD R5
P1
...
PN
MARK N
OLD PC
```

The subroutine would execute normally and return using the `RTS R5` instruction. This causes the contents of `R5` to be placed in the `PC` which then results in the execution of the instruction `MARK N`. The contents of the old `PC` are placed in `R5`.

`MARK N` causes: (1) the stack pointer to be adjusted to point to the old `R5` value; (2) the value now in `R5` (the old `PC`) to be placed on the `PC`; and (3) contents of the old `R5` to be popped into `R5` thus completing the return from subroutine.

The `MARK` instruction seems unique in several aspects:

- It appears to be the only PDP-11 instruction which used the register R5 implicitly. Thus, similarly to the PC (R7) and SP(R6), R5 should have had a mnemonic name. Had it?
- It can only be used meaningfully when put on the stack (Now we know that an executable stack is a bad idea, but that was then).

From my recollection, the PDP-11 C/UNIX calling conventions did not use the `MARK` instruction; calling special subroutines CSAV/CRET instead.

In what PDP-11 OS or programming environment was it actually used?

Were there other instruction set architectures with instructions designed specifically for use on the stack? Is it known who came up with the idea?

Comment: I don't know if it had a mnemonic name on the PDP-11, but the register for a similar kind of stack frame linkage is usually called base pointer (BP) or frame pointer (FP). Using an executable instruction during return is certainly predated by very early implementations of subroutines which modify a JMP (not on the stack, but e.g. directly before the subroutine) to do the return. Modification of instructions in memory was common long before CPUs with a specific stack.

Comment: Are you sure you got the MARK semantics correct? I am pretty sure it was **not** used to not signal "there's stuff on the stack", but rather to put the parameters into the program space following the JSR and have RTS return to n words beyond.

Comment: @tofro Do you see any mistakes in my retyping of the linked PDP-11 instuction set manual?

Comment: No - but I have seen another explanation - will try and find it.

Comment: @tofro It could be that its complicated and often misrepresented semantics had contributed to its disuse.

Comment: @dirkt Sure, FP would be a fitting mnemonic, and could be used in source code, but was it official? You can say that a modifiable jump directly before the subroutine and the MARK instruction have something in common (a "trampoline" of sorts between the return instruction and the next instruction in the caller), but my point about the MARK opcode is that it could only be used in the described fashion, it has no other use.

Comment: All I can say is that when I was taught PDP-11 MACRO, we were not taught this. Not for our code, nor for the exercises for when were wrote routines to be called by Fortran.

Comment: @WillHartung I won't be surprised if in practice using `MARK` resulted in a less compact code than using CRET-like epilogs, and if it was never used in any  programming system sold by DEC.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Partial answer:

If you compare the PDP-11 calling convention using a stack as described e.g. [here](https://people.cs.clemson.edu/~mark/subroutines/pdp11.html)

```
   ! parameters passed on stack
       ...
       mov   parm1,-(sp)
       mov   parm2,-(sp)
       jsr   pc,subr2
       add   #4,sp       ! adjust stack to remove parameters
       ...

   ! subroutine called with parameters on stack
   subr2:
       mov   r1,-(sp)   ! save r1 contents on stack
       ...
       mov   (sp)+,r1   ! restore r1 contents from stack
       rts   pc         ! return to instruction following jsr
```

with the one from the manual which makes use of `mark`

```
   ! caller
       mov   r5,-(sp)
       mov   parm1,-(sp)
       mov   parm2,-(sp)
       mov   #mark2,-(sp)
       mov   sp,r5
       jsr   pc,subr

   ! callee
   subr:
       mov   r1,-(sp)
       ...
       mov   (sp)+,r1
       rts   r5
```

one can see that the use of `mark` is actually less efficient (three commands instead of just one) than just adjusting `sp` after the call. If you add to this that, as remarked in the [report by Ritchie and Johnson](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/clcs.html), there are

> special short instructions on the PDP-11 that are used to bump the `sp` by two or four bytes; these instructions [...] apply [...] to procedures of one and two arguments.

(and they also mention an improvement with a slightly different calling convention), then the conclusion is that `mark` was something the designers of the PDP-11 dreamed up before fully understanding stack-based calling conventions (other PDPs like the PDP-8 didn't use a stack, and stored the PC in front of the subroutine...), and `mark` probably was never used in practice.

Another indication for this is that there are PDP-11 models that don't implement this instruction, and neither does the VAX in PDP-11 compatibility mode.

As an aside: On the x86 there was a similar development, when the `ENTER` and `LEAVE` instructions fell out of favour and where replaced by manipulating `SP` directly (in various ways).

Comment: Also note that the former allows r5 to be used as a general purpose register, leaving the program with 6 gp regs; whereas the mark version leaves the program with only 5 gp regs, which is a significant difference especially for early compilers whose register allocation wasn't that good, and that also shared the registers with the user program via the `register` keyword for special local variables in C.

Comment: My original thought was that as `MARK` and `SOB` weren't in the initial instruction set, programming practice using that initial instruction set had shown that these instructions would be beneficial. That proved to be correct for `SOB` but apparently wrong for `MARK`. Thus my question: how did that happen? Re x86, `ENTER` and `LEAVE` were at least used by production compilers for quite a while.

Comment: @ErikEidt Shouldn't it be "5 gp regs" and "4 gp regs" resp.?

Comment: ENTER was always slower than its equivalent instructions, so it was seldom used. LEAVE though was as fast or faster and always shorter so it was and continues to be used by compilers.

Comment: @LeoB. Um, it has "8" regs but since two of those are dedicated to a particular usage (r6 as sp, and r7 as pc) that leaves 6 gp regs (r0-r5) for programs to use for variables & temps -- unless the chosen calling convention also requires r5, in which case that leaves 5 gp regs (r0-r4) for programs & compilers to use as variables & temps, no?

Comment: @ErikEidt I was thinking C which usually required a frame pointer register as well. IIRC, the "register" keyword was honored for no more than 4 variables, not even 5.

Comment: @LeoB. Don't know how PDP-11 compilers did it, but a frame pointer can be avoided (so as to rely solely on the sp) by evaluating & pushing function arguments onto the stack in reverse order, namely right to left rather than the more obvious (and possibly desired) left to right.  C allows an implementation to do this since it doesn't prescribe the order of evaluation of operands (e.g. the parameters separated by the argument separator ",").  (There are of course, still practical concerns of language interoperability on the given platform).

Comment: @RossRidge IIRC, `ENTER` was used when optimization for space was requested.

Comment: @ErikEidt I think the C standard requires the parameters to be pushed in a certain order so that `VARARGS` can work. Maybe that stuff wasn't around at that time, or I am wrong?

Comment: @Wilson in K&R C times it was virtually mandatory for implementations to push arguments onto the stack in reverse order because there was no way for the caller to know how many arguments the callee was expecting or for the callee to know how many arguments the caller pushed except by convention. The modern C standard doesn't mandate an order for pushing arguments on to the stack *because it doesn't mandate a stack*.

Comment: @Wilson, you could push arguments in forwards order and still handle varargs, but it would basically require an extra parameter (passed out of band of the other parameters, e.g. in a dedicated register) that pointed to the first argument, or that held the arguments' (word) count.

Comment: `leave` is still used by compilers, `enter` not so much.

Answer (score 7):

I've seen claims by many, that MARK instruction has been borrowed from, no pun intended, Burroughs large systems, to make porting of UCSD Pascal p-System easier and more straightforward. As the chronology goes:

```
•1974 Pascal is running on the Burroughs B6700 at UCSD
•1976 UCSD Pascal is running on a Terak microcomputer.
```

I tried to investigate into this subject a little, and found out that there's a lot of reference between PDP-11 MARK instruction and p-System. Those are - the terminology used in UCSD p-code machine implementation: MP(mark pointer), FP(stack frame pointer) etc... [see here](https://homepages.cwi.nl/%7Esteven/pascal/book/10pcode.html). As well as if you take a look at UCSD Pascal I.5 MACRO-11 [source code](https://web.archive.org/web/20120113021501/http://invent.ucsd.edu/technology/cases/1995-prior/SD1991-807.shtml), you'll find pieces like this:

```
; SHORT LOCAL LOADS...16 OF THEM
 SLDLS:  .IRP    N,<1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,20>
         MOV     <N+N>+MSDLTA(MP),-(SP)
         BR      BACK
         .ENDR
```

where MSDLTA stands for, apparently, "Mark Stack ...something", and MP being assigned to R5:

```
 BK = %2
 BASE = %3
 IPC= %4
 MP = %5
 R0 = %0
 R1 = %1
 R2 = %2
 R3 = %3
 R4 = %4
 R5 = %5
 SP = %6
 PC = %7
```

I'm wondering if it's just a coincidence. Assumingly, the practice of using MARK had even been dropped at some earlier point, but the traces remained. It'd be interesting to see the sources of UCSD p-System I.4 and earlier versions for that matter. Unfortunately they're not opensourced as of yet, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Mark Stack Delta: `MSDLTA is the required offset from BASE or MP to point to the first variable of a data segment`. See page 94, [A UCSD Pascal P-Machine Implementation of a mincomputer](https://journals.upd.edu.ph/index.php/pej/article/download/8318/7264)

Comment: I have a disk image with Terak UCSD Pascal stashed somewhere, but a fully functional Terak emulator, able to run UCSD Pascal for the purpose of verifying if the `MARK` instruction is used, does not seem to exist.

Comment: I defenitely remember, that recent versions of Erzatz-11 can do. Using this kind of  config:
`;file terak.ini
set cpu 03 eis fis
; TK: takes over 177560, so move TT0: out of the way
set tt0: csr=177270
; graphics screen on CON2: (E11 console remains on CON1:)
assign tk: con2:
define key uarrow = chr$(26)
define key larrow = chr$(23)
define key rarrow = chr$(11)
define key darrow = chr$(12)
; some boot blocks check ROM signature to identify controller
load /rom null: 173000:173003
mou qx0: tera15.dsk /sector
;mou qx1: drive1.vol /sector
; switch to CON2:
primary 2
boot qx0:`

Comment: Btw, @LeoB. Greetings from all of the BK001x community on the Net! And greetz to Vak also ;)
Thank you both for your contribution to the computational science. Take care!

PS: And special greetings from Alexey Nilov! :)

Comment: @AlexTrusty Thank you! Alas, formatting in the comments does not work.

Comment: @LeoB. looks like it doesn't, sorry)

Comment: You can take a look at E11 config for Terak [here](https://imgur.com/IjLNEj1.png) if you will. Oh, btw, Terak's bitmap display emulation is only implemented in DOS and Windows versions of Ersatz-11 as of now.

Answer (score 1):

I vaguely recall that MARK was added for Fortran, but I don't recall my source for this.

As a long-time Macro-11 programmer, both kernel and user modes, I never used MARK.

Comment: I don't see it used for function calls in [UNIX V6](http://pdp11.aiju.de/) when I compile a sample Fortran program using `fc`.

Comment: Sorry - I meant the DEC Fortran compiler for PDP-11.  Probably the F4P implementation.